# Using static methods in enterprise application in JAVA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am working on a Enterprise java application which is essentially a HTTP server. There I need to use some constants and sort of utility functions for parsing, file I/O etc. I have used static methods and variables for this purpose, but someone pointed out to me that using static for this purpose is a bad choice since from performance and memory point of view.

While I do not agree with this argument, I also do not see any other choice. Even if I convert them to instance methods, and access through a singleton instance, the instance will be accessed by some static function.

So, I want to know if this is really a problem. And If it is, what is the best approach to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a problem. I don't see what's wrong with static fields here. They are fine for utility functions and constants.

Comment: Look at methods that you're considering as static and ask these questions: Do I need to store any state between successive calls to this method or methods related to it? Does the output of this method depend at all on any calls or settings that have happened before it was called? If the answers to both are no, then a static method is probably okay. Note, however, that if you're reimplementing a lot of base HTTP-server functionality, you'll be a lot better off using a framework that already does all the low-level stuff for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quite right that ultimately everything is run from a static `main()` method. And many functions are suitable for being made static, e.g. simple methods like those on `java.lang.Math`. Speed and memory-use are non-issues - a static method does not take up any more memory or run slower than any other method. Internally, it's exactly the same as any other method but is defined and runs on a class-instance instead of an instance of the class.

A problem I've found with static methods is that it's easy inadvertently to slip in some specific assumptions (e.g. where a directory is) which makes it harder to reuse the function elsewhere. It also can become much harder to test the code. When you're unit testing, you usually want to be able to test without doing *time-consuming) I/O - e.g. by mocking or stubbing out the I/O parts. If your method doesn't allow that, it's much harder. Singleton classes can cause similar testing difficulties.

Static methods tend to lead to functional or procedural, rather than object-oriented code. I find static methods useful as a functional layer of "syntactic sugar" above a rich domain model of objects.

It's also worth mentioning that there are loads of existing utilities classes around, such as [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) etc. They are well-written, heavily used and well-tested. You might consider looking at them before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ask yourself why do you have to use static method or singleton? When you plan to use static methods or singletons, you need to have a reason for it. In some cases that could be the best way.

There are two types of "static methods":

- "safe static method" - alawys produces the same result for the same parameters, does not modify any globals and call "unsafe static methods". Using these methods is ok - I would not worry.
- "unsafe static method" - a method that changes a global state or global or object. These methods are hard to test. Using these is very risky.

Some people tend to overuse static methods - especially the people that were used to procedural languages. The best way to eliminate this kind of thinking is to  to have thorough understanding of object-oriented principles and practices. The thing that I think can help a lot is TDD - static methods are hard to test, using TDD forces you to create "testable" code which is ussualy also a properly designed code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I can see much more benefit in using static methods for utility functions

- it will allow you to make constructor `private` which together with class marked as `final` clearly says that this class is a library
- it allow you to import methods statically like `import static SomeClass.someMethod;` so you don't have to write class name over and over again
- I really doubt that performance is a big problem if you are not going to have there 1000 methods (which is a really poor design anyway)

Answer (score 1):

> but someone pointed out to me that using static for this purpose is a bad choice since from performance and memory point of view

This is nonsenese or superstition or both!
Ask them for proof that a static method is slower, or uses more memory under otherwise equal circumstances.

Both approaches (avoid static at all cost / make everything static) are bad.

Answer (score 1):

Do you test your code?

With testing, the disfavor of `static` become obvious:

- you can't mock static methods[1](http://googletesting.blogspot.com.br/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html): If you `Util` class opens a file, then you *must* have that file when testing.
- you can't replace static methods.
- you can't make more specialized versions of those methods through subclassing the `Util` classes (and then changing what class is injected by the CDI container).

**Unless** you are building a true utility library that is unlikely to change (such as Apache Commons), **do** use instance methods and do use singletons.

Whoever picks your code in the future and needs to change it will thank you.

Follow up: [Static Methods are Death to Testability](http://googletesting.blogspot.com.br/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html)

[1](http://googletesting.blogspot.com.br/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html): Actually, you can mock `static` methods with tools such as PowerMock. But they are way too invasive and the tests they generate are so brittle they miss the purpose of testing. The very need of such a tool is a strong indicator of problems in your codebase. (In time, those tools are useful for legacy systems testing.)

Comment: Sometimes there is just no choice, for example a method doing some String manipulations (without using or even changing global state). We can't extend String. Now what?

Comment: There, in the answer: *"Unless you are building a true utility library that is unlikely to change (such as Apache Commons), do use instance methods and do use singletons."* If you are building a library (such as `StringUtils`), then, by all means, use static methods. But if you are creating utility methods (just to avoid code duplication) and you only will use, then don't make them `static`. You don't have to. If in the tests you want to use the actual version (instead of a mock) then use them. The problem with `static` is that there is no such choice.

Comment: When you say "do use singletons", I'm guessing you meant to say "do *not* use singletons", right?

Comment: @aetheria No, I meant singletons should be used (as the matter of multiple unecessary instances has to be addressed). If using a DI container (such as spring), every injectable class (the `@component`s)  are singletons by default. This is the optimal case (the class itself thus has no `static` methods). If DI is not available, then the Singleton pattern (as described by the Gang of Four) should be used, but with an additional `static` method to set the global instance for the purpose of tests (as suggested by Michael Feathers in his 'Working Effectivelly with Legacy Code' book).

Comment: OK, I seriously don't agree with that approach! The choice isn't either a DI container or singletons via a static method. You can do DI happily without a container. If you want a single instance, create a single instance with `new MyClass()` and then inject it into other objects that you also create `new AnotherClass(myClass)`. You don't need AnotherClass to obtain its dependency via `MyClass.newInstance()`. Zikes! DI containers make DI so much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Of course you can do constructor injection. You can do whatever-injection-you-want if you don't want to use a DI container. You just don't realize the coupling generated across a whole chain of instantiations  by doing constructor injection of a utility class. If the supposed-to-be single instance is created at bootstrap time (e.g. the `main()` method), it sure is "Zikes!"simpler to just pass that instance around in constructors A, B, C, and D, when just class E uses it. Who cares about the coupling, right? Just because DI can happen through construc/setter/w/e, doesn't mean you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

In short, unless this `Util` class is huge, then this isn't going to bring forth the apocalypse. You shouldn't just ignore the use of static classes, because they are useful, and they also look a lot nicer.

```
MyFileReader.readFile("C:/file.txt");
```

Looks nicer than:

```
MyFileReader mfr = new MyFileReader();
mfr.readFile("C:/file.txt");
```

And, if you change it to instance methods, you have to *create* the object every single time you want to use it. I'm sure that will also impact performance. Your application will use more memory, but provided the class is a reasonable size (and if it's not it should be split up), then you should be okay.

Comment: So the I/O classes, like `FileReader` or `BufferedReader` are implemented in a non-static way because of performance?

Comment: Other classes use these as instances. There is a performance difference, but then again, `Files.readAllLines()` exists to.

Comment: @Christian No, those classes are implemented as instances because you usually want more stateful operation than "read this entire file at once", and something like this `MyFileReader` will be using the stateful I/O instances inside its static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using the static methods is really a Performance Issue as it is resolved at compile time.
Coming to the memory point of view, I dont agree for that as well.
For static constants they are loaded once used as many time required.
For static method it is same as Instance method except in case of Instance a hidden called "this".

But where to use static method is the most important thing. If your method really need to do some common functionality which may be used in different scenarios, I go for static methods.
In your case , you are right, Static methods are use full for utility function. 
How ever really need to check file I/O operation what it does , if some kind of context is saved in the class level for such operation, then it is not advisable.

Utility function is actually used in many places and using the Singleton in this case introduce bit performance problem.